How can i remove only single lines between text to chunk it up?
I have a text file:
title

header
topic one two three


hello harry

i want to remove only single lines between text to get:
title
header
topic one two three


hello harry

how i can do this using python?
data = open('data.txt').read().replace('\n', '')

the above removes all

''.join(your_doc.split('\n',1))

Use a regular expression to match all instances of \n\n exactly and replace them with single \n. You must match \n\n because each line in your example input file will end in \n (so a blank line between paragraphs is \n\n).
data = open('data.txt').read()
pattern = r'(?<!\n)\n\n(?!\n)'
re.sub(pattern, '\n', data)

The first part (?<!\n) checks that the preceding character is not a newline.
The middle \n\n checks for a double newline.
The end part (?!\n) checks that the following character is not a newline.
So this regex solution is generalized and will match all instances of \n\n without touching \n or \n\n\n etc.

this is what I originally tried and posted but then I realised that actually it doesn't really work because it doesn't actually do anything like what the author intended - single lines remain where they were and multiple instances of \n just lose one of these \n's. actually rather puzzled how this answer ended up upvoted and accepted while my solution that actually works gets downvoted ..

I believe it works exactly as intended. As explained in the answer, it removes a \n instance only when there is a double instance - meaning if there is a single instance then it remains untouched and if there are 3 or more instances (as in when there is a double line between paragraphs) that too remains untouched, thus working as the author intended and only removing single lines between paragraphs.

Iterate over lines and only keep those that are either not empty or where both surrounding lines are non-empty.
lines = text.split('\n')
n_lines = len(lines)
'\n'.join(x
 for i, x in enumerate(lines)
 if x != ''
   or lines[i - 1 if i else 1] == ''
   or lines[i + 1 if i < n_lines else i - 1] == ''
)

Output as expected:
title
header
topic one two three


hello harry

